# How can I get a higher number of the visitors countries in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've been running server side (WAP) GA on my mobile site for the past week and the no1 visitor country is "(none)" at approx. 37%. 
Is there any way of getting more of the visitors locations rather than it coming up as "(none)"?
The vast majority of the traffic is coming from mobile browsers that don't support JS (that's why I'm using the server side implementation).

I've heard that this may have something to do with Opera browsers but I'm not sure how accurate that information is.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Opera Mini browser makes a significant impression on the location stats so after some more research I found the below info from this link:

http://my.opera.com/community/openweb/idopera/

> Opera Mini achieves its speed and compression by rendering on one of our data centres in Norway, Iceland, USA, China or The Moon. Therefore, a crude check for IP address with REMOTE_ADDR will give you the address of one of the data centres, rather than of the user.
>
> Developers should instead check the The X-Forwarded-For (XFF) HTTP header field, which is a de facto standard for identifying the originating IP address of a client connecting to a web server through an HTTP proxy or load balancer.

After making this change to the ga.php script, the visitor country "none" has gone from 37% to 16.5% approx.
The result speaks for itself.
Hope this helps someone.